# How to set min-font-size in CSS

Tags: html, css, font-size

I want to set a minimum font size to every element in my HTML page.

For example if there are elements with font-size less then 12px, then they will change to 12px.
But if there are elements with font-size grater then 12px, they will not change.

Is there any way to do it with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. While you can set a base font size on `body` using the `font-size` property, anything after that that specifies a smaller size will override the base rule for that element. In order to do what you are looking to do you will need to use Javascript.

You could iterate through the elements on the page and change the smaller fonts using something like this:

```
$("*").each( function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (parseInt($this.css("fontSize")) < 12) {
        $this.css({ "font-size": "12px" });   
    }
});
```

Here is a Fiddle where you can see it done: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/LfdL8/2/

Comment: Is there a simple way to find with jQuery elements with size less then 12px?

Comment: @nrofis - sure, see the edit to my answer above. Cheers!

Comment: Iterating over ALL the elements on a page and changing a CSS property seems like a really bad idea from a performance stand point. I'm not an expert on what triggers reflows but you could inadvertently be reflowing the page a lot with this approach. I do not recommend this approach.

Comment: I'm with @AvandAmiri - this is a bad approach in the sense that this kind of thinking leads to many other solutions like this on a page, which then leads to non-performant sites and even memory leaks that will crash your app. The true answer to this is (until font-size max becomes a legitimately usable thing) is to tighten up architecture - design and implement a good system that just does things properly. There should be no font sizes on a page that are "accidental".

Comment: But font sizes that are specified with vw should be accompanied with a min font size or else they become so small in xs.

Comment: @AndersLindén In that case, set a minimum font size in a media query, for instance, if you don't want your font size to go below 10px:

    `p{ font-size: 1vw }
    
    @media (max-width: 1000px){
        p{ font-size: 10px }
    }`

Comment: wait, so if you have an element with (say) `width:10vw; min-width:1in` then you can't prevent the font size from continuing to shrink even though the element isn't getting any smaller???!

Comment: What's the result of $this.css("fontSize"), if somebody has a font-size of 10% ?

Answer (score 299):

In CSS3 there is a simple but brilliant hack for that:

```
font-size:calc(12px + 1.5vw);
```

This is because the static part of calc() defines the minimum. Even though the dynamic part might shrink to something near 0.

Comment: Great method: I made a codepen for this but for height. Change 'vh' to 'vw' to see how this works with width. http://codepen.io/iamnotsam/pen/JWXVxM

Comment: Although this is a nice hack, I'd say this isn't truly a solution as it affects the font-size when the size is above minimum, so you have to put up with that extra `12px` (in this case) at all times.

Comment: if you use stylus and want a helper to set a size `font-size "calc(%s + (%s - %s))" % (minSize size baseFontSize)`

Comment: This won't allow dynamic resize of the window, you'll have to refresh the page to see changes.

Comment: Makes everything bigger with no regard to the maximum threshold.  The original poster asked to increase font sizes for only those that are 12px or less.

Comment: Only applicable in some use cases

Answer (score 87):

As of mid-December 2019, the CSS4 min/max-function is exactly what you want: 

**(tread with care, this is very new, older browsers (aka IE & msEdge) don't support it just yet)**
 
(supported as of Chromium 79 & Firefox v75)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max

Example:

```
blockquote {
    font-size: max(1em, 12px);
}
```

That way the font-size will be 1em (if 1em > 12px), but at least 12px.

<del>Unfortunatly this awesome CSS3 feature isn't supported by any browsers yet, but I hope this will change soon!</del>

**Edit:**

This used to be part of CSS3, but was then re-scheduled for CSS4.
As per [December 11th 2019](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408?hl=en), support arrived in Chrome/Chromium 79 (including on Android, and in Android WebView), and as such also in Microsoft Chredge aka Anaheim including Opera 66 and Safari 11.1 (incl. iOS)

Comment: seriously, why do standards committees always remove the stuff that would actually make my job doable!?

Comment: @Michael, the CSS WG removes stuff mostly because lack of implementer's interest or priority. It needs two independent implementations to get a CSS feature in a final W3C Recommendation. There is no point in writing a paper and nobody wants to push it into real world software. So you should ask browser vendors ...

Comment: Great find!  Can use with css variables to set min/max.  Example: `:root {
    --responsive-font-size-primary: min(2em, max(0.5em, 5vmin));
}` making usage simple: `font-size: var(--responsive-font-size-primary);`

Comment: @Corey Alix: Cool, just noticed support for that has arrived as per December 11th, 2019. Thread with care, all non-Chromium based browsers don't support it just yet. But support for it in Chrome is very cool news.

Comment: @Michael: Good news - it's now implemented ! (per mid-December 2019)

Comment: I believe this is not what the OP asked about. I believe the question was about adding a single declaration to override all other declarations when the font sizes are smaller than a given one.

Comment: min and max are supported in [most browsers now](https://caniuse.com/css-math-functions).

Comment: as of 2022 this should be the answer to set min, max values to font-size like we do for height and width

Comment: 2022 - it seem's that we having full support for this. So this should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

CSS has a clamp() function that holds the value between the upper and lower bound. 
The clamp() function enables the selection of the middle value in the range of values between the defined minimum and maximum values.

It simply takes three dimensions:

1. Minimum value.
2. List item
3. Preferred value Maximum allowed value.

try with the code below, and check the window resize, which will change the font size you see in the console. i set maximum value `150px` and minimum value `100px`.

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
    console.log($('#element').css('font-size'));
});
console.log($('#element').css('font-size'));
```

```css
h1{
    font-size: 10vw; /* Browsers that do not support "MIN () - MAX ()" and "Clamp ()" functions will take this value.*/
    font-size: max(100px, min(10vw, 150px)); /* Browsers that do not support the "clamp ()" function will take this value. */
    font-size: clamp(100px, 10vw, 150px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <h1 id="element">THIS IS TEXT</h1>
</center>
```

Answer (score 9):

Looks like I'm a bit late but for others with this issue try this code

```
p { font-size: 3vmax; }
```

use whatever tag you prefer and size you prefer (replace the 3)

```
p { font-size: 3vmin; }
```

is used for a max size.

Comment: vmax and vmin are actually used to specifiy values relative to the viewpoint/page size. The min and max refer to the minimum/maxium viewport not the min or max of the font size - which is what the op was asking. (e.g. if height is larger than width of the viewport than vmax is equal to 100vmax = height of viewport and 100vmin = width of viewport)

Answer (score 9):

Use a media query. Example:
This is something im using the original size is 1.0vw but when it hits 1000 the letter gets too small so I scale it up

```
@media(max-width:600px){
    body,input,textarea{
         font-size:2.0vw !important;
    }
}
```

This site I m working on is not responsive for >500px but you might need more. The pro,benefit for this solution is you keep font size scaling without having super mini letters and you can keep it js free.

Comment: ugh.  this ties the element to the resolution of the window, does it not?  which means that in the general you would need a separate media query for each element on the page.

Answer (score 9):

```
.class {
    font-size: clamp(minimum-size, prefered-size, maximum-size)
}
```

using this you could set it up so prefered and max values are 5vw but the minimum is 15px or something so it won't go over 5vw but if 5vw < 15px it will stick to 15px

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Answer (score 4):

A recent feature added to CSS is min() which chooses the minimum value of its parameters.

So in the following code, when the viewport is big (>1500px in this case), the font-size is capped to 30px.

However for any viewport smaller than 1500px, the other value is used: e.g. when viewport is 1000px, then the font-size will be 20px. This means it can be quite responsive.

```
p {
  font-size: min(2vw, 30px);
}
```

Here's a Codepen with min() for container width and p text:
https://codepen.io/code0312/pen/dyWJLmB

But note, if you later manually set a font size greater than what you put here, that will still override this declaration.

Answer (score 3):

CSS Solution:

```
.h2{
  font-size: 2vw
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .h2{
    /* Minimum font size */
    font-size: 14px
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .h2{
    /* Maximum font size */
    font-size: 24px
  }
}
```

Just in case if some need scss mixin:

```
///
/// Viewport sized typography with minimum and maximum values
///
/// @author Eduardo Boucas (@eduardoboucas)
///
/// @param {Number}   $responsive  - Viewport-based size
/// @param {Number}   $min         - Minimum font size (px)
/// @param {Number}   $max         - Maximum font size (px)
///                                  (optional)
/// @param {Number}   $fallback    - Fallback for viewport-
///                                  based units (optional)
///
/// @example scss - 5vw font size (with 50px fallback),
///                 minumum of 35px and maximum of 150px
///  @include responsive-font(5vw, 35px, 150px, 50px);
///

@mixin responsive-font($responsive, $min, $max: false, $fallback: false) {
  $responsive-unitless: $responsive / ($responsive - $responsive + 1);
  $dimension: if(unit($responsive) == 'vh', 'height', 'width');
  $min-breakpoint: $min / $responsive-unitless * 100;

  @media (max-#{$dimension}: #{$min-breakpoint}) {
    font-size: $min;
  }

  @if $max {
    $max-breakpoint: $max / $responsive-unitless * 100;

    @media (min-#{$dimension}: #{$max-breakpoint}) {
      font-size: $max;
    }
  }

  @if $fallback {
    font-size: $fallback;
  }

  font-size: $responsive;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible with plain CSS,
but you can do a pretty expensive jQuery operation like:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/zazeh/3/edit)**

```
$('*').css('fontSize', function(i, fs){
  if(parseInt(fs, 10) < 12 ) return this.style.fontSize = "12px";
});
```

<sub>Instead of using the *Global Selector* `*` I'd suggest you (if possible) to be more specific with your selectors.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your above comment, you're OK doing this with jQuery — here goes:

```
// for every element in the body tag
$("*", "body").each(function() {
  // parse out its computed font size, and see if it is less than 12
  if ( parseInt($(this).css("font-size"), 10) < 12 )
    // if so, then manually give it a CSS property of 12px
    $(this).css("font-size", "12px")
});
```

A cleaner way to do this might be to have a "min-font" class in your CSS that sets font-size: 12px, and just add the class instead:

```
$("*", "body").each(function() {
  if ( parseInt($(this).css("font-size"), 10) < 12 )
    $(this).addClass("min-font")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `font-min-size` and `font-max-size` CSS properties were [removed](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#changes-2018-04-10) from the CSS Fonts Module Level 4 specification (and never implemented in browsers AFAIK). And the CSS Working Group replaced the CSS examples with `font-size: clamp(...)` which doesn't have the greatest browser support yet so we'll have to wait for browsers to support it. See example in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp#Examples.

Answer (score 0):

It will work perfectly with 50px. Which will act as a static and thus as min-width.

```css
font-size: calc(50px + 5vw);
```