# Use vw with minimum and maximum font size

Tags: css

I want to use the `vw` unit for my font size but I want to limit the max and the min font size that a user can get to. Is there a way to do this with only CSS?

Comment: check your ans is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61892360/6293856

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries?
Essentially, depending on the min/max values of height/width , you can adjust the font size to a particular value of vw.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
p{
    font-size:3vw;
}}
```

Check the link for details.[link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)