# JavaScript onresize event fires multiple times

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble trying running a function only once when onresize event is triggered, I have looked at this questions [DOM onresize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500312/javascript-onresize-event) but I'm not using jQuery and can't get that function to work without. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post some code - from the top of my head, use a boolean?

Comment: The linked answer doesn't need jQuery to work, pure JavaScript do. Read again

Comment: $(window).resize($.debounce(1000, function() {
   // Handle your resize only once total, after a one second calm.
   ...
}));

I have tried using this without jquery but it doesn't work, I'm using this inside a firefox extension

Comment: you can't use jQuery's namespace (`$`) as in `$(window).resize` if you don't have jQuery, instead you'll have to bind it in the `window.onresize = function() {` (or another listener) and use the `Cowboy` namespace as described in the author's page. I'd personally use a `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The resize event is called once for every frame during the resizing operation. If you want to call it when resizing is finished, just set timer with a callback function.

```
var timeOut = null;

window.onresize = function(){
    if (timeOut != null)
        clearTimeout(timeOut);

    timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
        // YOUR RESIZE CODE HERE
    }, 500);
};
```

Comment: Of course, if the user holds the window size steady for half a second, this method will not quite work as expected. It's a good answer, but not foolproof.

Comment: I don't think that matters. That type of behavior may even be what he's looking for.

Comment: @Kolink: There is no possibility to detect the end of a resize action.

Comment: "If you can't solve it with `setTimeout`, you're not using enough `setTimeout`s."

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `debounce` implementation [from underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-58):

```
  function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
      var context = this, args = arguments;
      var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
      };
      if (immediate && !timeout) func.apply(context, args);
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    };
  }
  window.onresize = debounce(function() {
      // Your code here
  }, 500);
```

Or use the [library from the linked question](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/). Without jQuery, it is `Cowboy.debounce(...)`.